# One-to-one mapping where primary key is foreign key - what annotations are required

Tags: java, jpa

I have the following tables:

```
Table: MyEntity {
    MyEntityId: primary-key, auto-generated
    // other fields ommited
}

Table: MyEntityLastAction {
    MyEntityId: primary-key
    // other fields ommited
}
```

- `MyEntityLastAction.MyEntityId` has a constraint that it must exist in `MyEntity`. (This is a foreign key)
- `MyEntityLastAction` is a VERY BIG record, hence why it is split out into another table

I am failing to setup the entity annotations correctly. Here is roughly where I am:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public long myEntityId;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    public MyEntityLastAction lastAction;
}

@Entity
public class MyEntityLastAction {
    @Id
    public long myEntityId;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "MyEntity", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MyEntityId")
    public MyEntity myEntity;
}
```

I image trying to run the following:

```
MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity();
myEntity.lastAction = new MyEntityLastAction();

em.save(myEntity);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `@MapsId` annotation. This allows you to have `@OneToOne` with shared primary key.

See the below code for reference:

```
@Entity
class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public long myEntityId;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "myEntity", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    public MyEntityLastAction lastAction;
}

@Entity
class MyEntityLastAction {
    @Id
    public long myEntityId;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="MyEntityId") 
    @MapsId     
    public MyEntity myEntity;
}
```

And to save the entity:

```
        MyEntity me = new MyEntity();
        me.lastAction = new MyEntityLastAction();
        me.lastAction.myEntity = me;
        entityManager.persist(me);
```

Comment: `@MapsId` only applies to embedded IDs.

Comment: @AlvinThompson Are you sure `@MapsId` only works for emdedded IDs. You may want to try the above code before down voting. I am able to save the relation properly.

Comment: From the docs: Designates a ManyToOne or OneToOne relationship attribute that provides the mapping for an EmbeddedId primary key, an attribute within an EmbeddedId primary key, or a simple primary key of the parent entity. The value element specifies the attribute within a composite key to which the relationship attribute corresponds. If the entity's primary key is of the same Java type as the primary key of the entity referenced by the relationship, the value attribute is not specified.

Comment: Even if it happens to work, it doesn't work the right way and will likely break in the future if things change.

Comment: @AlvinThompson `@MapsId` is introduced in JPA 2.0 as per the following [link](https://dzone.com/articles/onetoone-shared-primary-key) PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotation is replaced with two annotations: MapsId, which defines thatSecundus identifier will be determined by Primus identifier, and JoinColumn, specifying which column in SECUNDUS table will be used for joining. Please have a look.

Comment: I don't doubt that you tried it and things seem to work. I don't doubt that the blogger in the link you mention tried it and things seemed to work. My issue is that the documentation is clear what use case `MapsId` is for, and it's not this use case. That means it isn't required to work with this use case. It may not work with other JPA implementations. It may not work in future versions of whatever JPA implementation you're using. Two years down the road if this breaks you won't know why.

Comment: @AlvinThompson Javadocs for MapsId says "Designates a ManyToOne or OneToOne relationship ... for an EmbeddedId primary key, an attribute within an EmbeddedId primary key, or a simple primary key of the parent entity". The key is MapsId provides mapping for **a simple primary key of the parent entity.** And using `MapsId` is a valid and supported by JPA as well. You may want to refer to [JPA-Spec-2.1](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf) **Case(b)** section on Page 37 that shows the usage of `MapsId` in shared PK context.

Comment: Hmm...I guess I'll have to eat crow. Case 4b (at the bottom of page 37) does indeed seem to apply here. The use of `MapsId` there makes little logical sense from a grouping perspective, but there it is. I'm guessing this became a standard "by typo". Down vote withdrawn.

Comment: @AlvinThompson Infact, this discussion made me go through JPA spec and other links and in the process I am glad this helped me refresh my memory on some of other hibernate topics as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues: First, your `mappedBy` attribute should be the field name in `MyEntity`(in this case `lastAction`). Second, since the `mappedBy` attribute indicates that the other side of the relationship handles how the two objects should be linked together, the join column annotation needs to be moved there. This should work:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public long myEntityId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "MyEntityId")
    public MyEntityLastAction lastAction;
}

@Entity
public class MyEntityLastAction {
    @Id
    public long myEntityId;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "lastAction", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    public MyEntity myEntity;
}
```

Note that if you're creating a new `MyEntity` with JPA, it won't cascade the new `MyEntityLastAction` within it. You'll have to first persist `MyEntity`, then set the ID in `MyEntityLastAction` to the one assigned to `MyEntity`, then persist `MyEntityLastAction`.