# One to one relation in hibernate saving child with parent id

Tags: hibernate

I have a parent, static table. I wanted to save child with parent id, but I am facing an issue which is:

org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing.

Parent

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy="office")
  private List<Employee> employies = new ArrayList<Employee>();
```

Child

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="office_id", referencedColumnName="id")
private Office office;
```

Comment: Please, share your mapping to can help you better (probably will be something related with CascadeType). Anyway, the exception is clear, with your current setup, you need to save the child entity before to put it in the persistent context, because at the moment you're saving the parent entity with the child related (this one is transient, out of the persistent context).

Comment: Could be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35873058/one-to-one-mapping-where-primary-key-is-foreign-key-what-annotations-are-requi. Have a look

Comment: Dani I update with question

Comment: Can you add code where you are persisting Data. and what is name of Parent Table and Child Table ?